# Can't force image to be inserted here even with using begin{figure}[H]

Tags: floats

I'm using latex to write a lab manual for a computer class. for this purpose I should describe the steps of the lab step by step and each step must be followed by an image. but the problem is when I write a bunch of words and then call begin{figure} even with use of [H] it ignores my order and puts words together and two images in tandem. I want each image to be right were I tell it as reference to the texts, not to float.
I appreciate your help tnx

Comment: If you're only interested in including the image (without a caption), just use `\includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}`. If you want the image to be stand-alone as a paragraph on its own, prepend with `\noindent`.

Comment: Have you loaded the `float` package?

Comment: Welcome to TSX! Could you give us a Minimal (non)Working Example? This would help us help you.

Comment: I want it to have caption, I just loaded graphicx not float package. what does float do?

Comment: The `float` package enables the `[H]` option, amongst other things.

Comment: there is really no point in using `H` here. The only reason for using `figure` is to allow it to float, if you don't want it to float, just don't use `figure`

Answer (score 15):

In order to use the `[H]` option, you need to load the [float package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[H]
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\caption{They \emph{all} float down here.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You are slightly unfortunate, in that omitting this doesn't generate an error or warning. It does disable other positioning options, so that figures are moved to the end of the document (e.g. try deleting `\usepackage{float}` from the above example).

Comment: if you load fixltx2e in its 2014 release you would get the error `Unknown float option 'H'` couldn't really change the default behaviour

Comment: Exactly, I got that error, then I searched for {figure}[H] and landed to this location :-D